# Не могу добавить bot.polling в конце проекта [ЗАКРЫТО]

Tags: бот, telegram

Писал телеграм бота, немогу его протестить. Иммено в этом проекте при попытках добавить `bot.polling()` не видит библиотеку telebot. Могу добавить в начале и середине проекта, не иммено в конце не подчиняется.
[image: Фрагмент кода в конце проекта]

Ошибка:

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'polling'
```

Comment: А вы случайно не назвали один из хендлеров именем `bot`? Если да, то переименуйте его.

Comment: ЛУЧШИЙ! Спасибо, долго бы голову ломал.